# Printing the steps of a function composition

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming, lambda

I have this code:

```
 def apply_all (fs, x):
        def reducer (acc, f):
            (seq, x) = acc
            next = f (x)
            print((seq + [next], next))
            return (seq + [next], next)
        return [x] + reduce(reducer, fs, ([], x)) [0]

 print(apply_all(f_list,4))
```

It works perfectly to accomplish what I need. However, I need to turn this into one line using the map() and reduce() functions, and presumably lambda functions too. Any ideas?

Comment: @Reinderien My bad! I fixed it now (:

Comment: May I ask why a one-liner is required? `map`, `reduce` and `lambda` are all code-smells to me, where more verbose and clearer approaches are likely to exist. Those would then take multiple lines to write however. Other than that, your code is hard to understand. Please make it executable (`f_list` is not defined, `reduce` is not imported, an example for `f_list` would be nice)

Comment: Why create a function inside a function?

Answer (score -1):

As I could get from your code you're trying to implement a simple sum accumulator function. This should look like:

```
def apply_all(some_list, initial_value):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, some_list, initial_value)
```